# MySql select min, max conditionally without subselect in Yii2

Tags: mysql, yii2, max, min

I have this kind of data in a table:

```
id a1 a2
01 _1 _1
01 _1 _2
01 _1 _3
01 _2 _1
01 _2 _2
01 _2 _3
```

is it possible to select min and max something like this:

```
select ... min(a2 where a1=1)
```

it is a part of a bigger joined set of tables and I don't know how to implement subselect in yii2 so I would like to find a way to avoid subselects, if possible. Can you please point me to the right direction? Many thanks!

Comment: Should be possible but you should explain better your need .. try add a proper sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a simple way is based on the use of   CASE WHEN inside the aggregation function  (min/max ..)  eg

```
MIN( CASE WHEN a1 = 1 then a2 else a_proper_value END)
```

where a_proper_value is the value that you want assing in the case a1<> 1

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! Exactly what I needed.